# Webots e-puck turn 90 degrees

Tags: webots

How can I make a e-puck robot turn 90 degrees into a certain direction in Webots ?
I tryed using `wb_robot_step(TIME_STEP)` to make the robot rotate for a  certain amount of time but I didnt quite get it.

I also read somewhere online that I could possibly use the InertialUnit module to get the position of the robot on the y axis and rotate the robot until the angle is correct, but I didn't find any examples on that either.

Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you:

```
bool turn90ccw();   // Turn robot 90 degrees ccw in place
```

Just call this function where ever you need.

Comment: I got an error : `undefined reference to "turn90ccw" ` Is this function part of a library I need to import ?

Comment: Hey @ROBlackSnail!
Sorry for being Late. Which libraries are you using at this time?

Comment: You may see a working example here:
[Github we-bots](https://github.com/gopi231091/Bug0-Algorithm-Implementation-on-E-Puck-Robot/blob/master/e-puck.c)

Comment: I didn't quite get it. I resigned to turning the robot for a certain amount of time. Thank you anyway for your time !

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is to get the current position of each wheel using the position sensors API (https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/positionsensor), then knowing the radius of the wheels and the distance between the wheels you can compute the required rotation of each wheel (which you can measure using again the position sensors).

Using an inertial unit is indeed a solution, using the inertial unit API (https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/inertialunit) you can know the current orientation of the robot, then you can rotate until the orientation changed by 90 degrees.